# How to make "alt+f2" to reload PATH variable without rebooting

Tags: shell, fedora, gnome

When I append new path like `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/shortcuts"` to `/etc/profile`, I must reboot for `alt+f2 run application dialog` to reload the `PATH` to make `alt+f2` effective .

Is there a way to do that without rebooting?

EDIT:

Is there a way to do that without rebooting or re-loggining?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can just source the `/etc/profile` (it is what reboot does).

```
source /etc/profile
```

Comment: I don't use gnome, but would sourcing from any gnome-terminal actually effect the `PATH` for the desktop shell itself rather than the individual shell in use by the terminal?

Comment: This would not take effect for whole gnome (there is no way to pass environment variables to parent processes). For that, OP should re-login (which is still less intrusive than rebooting).

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure what `PATH` the `ALT+F2` run command would use in gnome shell, but was fairly sure sourcing in a gnome-terminal wouldn't effect the parent process. Thanks.

Comment: It dose not work as what you said "This would not take effect for whole gnome". But I don't want to re-login either :(